# How to initialize a string and store value in llvm IR

Tags: string, llvm, llvm-c++-api

How can I initialize a local string in llvm IR. I know how to do Int using AllocaInst and StoreInst. Is there similliar ways to initialize string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you create a constant `GlobalVariable` that holds a byte array representing your string. Any `GlobalVariable` is of pointer type, so you can use it in your function right away.

For example, you can use `getelementptr` instruction in conjunction with `load` to access string characters.

Comment: So it has to be global?

Comment: Well, you can allocate your string on the stack within your function and then initialize it by consecutive `store`s. But that would mean the string will be reinitialized with the same value **every time** you call it, which is inefficient.

Comment: where is the optimizer?